# Graph API to access a page's conversations

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I'm trying to get a facebook page's conversations using the Graph API, even after giving the permission 'read_page_mailboxes', it still shows that I do not have that permission. Am I missing anything?. Is it possible to read a page's chat conversations?. Please can someone guide me step by step on this?. I would really appreciate any help. I'm stuck since 2 days.Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 </head>
 <body>
    <script>
    // initialize and setup facebook js sdk
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : <appid>,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.5'
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are                
                connected.';
                document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not      
                logged in.'
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not     
                logged into Facebook.';
            }
        });
    };
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                console.log("in login:"+response.access_token);
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are 
                connected.';
                document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not     
                logged in.'
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not    
                logged into Facebook.';
            }
        }, {scope:"read_page_mailboxes,read_mailbox"});
    }

    // getting basic user info
    function getInfo() {
            FB.api(
            "/{page_id}?fields=conversations",
            function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
                console.log(response);
                /* handle the result */
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                response.access_token;
            }
            else{
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="status"></div>
<button onclick="getInfo()">Get Info</button>
<button onclick="login()" id="login">Login</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use a page access token

Comment: Can you please elaborate in steps if you don't mind?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for page access token?

Comment: /{page-id}?fields=access_token
As per documentation, this will give me the page access token.
Now, how do I use this to get conversations?

Comment: You need to pass it as an additional parameter with your FB.API call.